# PulseAudio volume control switch widget for XFCE

Tags: pulseaudio, xfce, widgets

Is there a xfce desktop switch widget for pulseaudio volume control? I have a wireless speaker and I hate having to open pulseaudio and change the output setting everytime I turn it on or off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For pulseaudio there is `module-switch-on-connect` designed to switch the output sink to any new sink as soon as a connection was established.

To test this module we can issue the following command in a terminal:

```
pactl load-module module-switch-on-connect
```

After restarting the pulseaudio server (`pulseaudio -k`) this module will be unloaded again.

In case we are happy with the way it operates we can always load this module with out `default.pa` (usually located in `/etc/pulse/`) by adding the following line

```
load-module module-switch-on-connect
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is, it is called pasystray

```
sudo apt-get install pasystray
```

press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type

```
pasystray
```

to start it up.

Next, you need to add the "notification area" to the xfce panel if not already added.

Finally, you will see a speaker icon on the desktop panel. Click the icon to adjust the speaker. Go to startup applications and add it there to make it start up at startup.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in "Audio Mixer Plugin".
Probably it is included in the `xfce4-mixer` package.

Comment: no it's not that is not for pulseaudio

Comment: I can do it in Xfce 4.10 and Pulseaudio 4.0.
Like this screen shot (http://prntscr.com/7g16ey).
I do not know that the other version.

Comment: absent in Xenial but available here https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/mint_import/rafaela/import/base/xfce4-mixer